# Alternative to CONTAINS method?

Tags: string, contains, anonymous-types

Giving the string below with "server type" separated by comma:

string serverTypeList = "DB, IIS, CMDB";

//server.Type in the loop below should have value of "MDB"

My problem is that in this scenario it will return TRUE because "MDB" string is inside the serverTypeList.
I need it to return TRUE only if it matches a type of "MDB" and not "CMDB":

...

```
from site in SiteManager.Sites
from server in site.Servers
where
  serverTypeList.Contains(server.Type)
select new Server()
{ ID=server.ID, SiteName=site.Name }
```

...

How can I change the code above?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(", " + serverTypeList + ", ").Contains(", " + server.Type + ", ")
```

is one standard way to handle this.  I'm not clear on the language you're using, so I don't know the exact syntax you would need, but the general idea is to ensure that the term appears between delimiters by forcing delimiters before and after the list string.